# Aggregate Login Control [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Is there a control out in the world that allows a user to log in to a website with MS Passport (Windows Live ID, whatever), Facebook, OpenID, etc. all in one control?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Even better, Windows Live is now an OpenID provider: http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on StackOverflow podcast 30 - JanRain RPX has beaten me. Sad face for me.

[JanRain RPX](https://rpxnow.com/how_it_works)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any control that allows all of them, but the API's are pretty simple that would allow you to implement it yourself.